# What does the extra version information in a conda environment yaml mean?

Tags: conda

I use conda by building a conda environment and then exporting a yaml file that describes the environment so I can reproduce it. Here is a portion of that yaml file:

```
  - parquet-cpp=1.5.1=2
  - parse=1.19.0=pyh44b312d_0
  - parse_type=0.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pathspec=0.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyh9f0ad1d_2
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
  - pip=22.0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
```

I'm intrigued to know what the thing at the end of each of those packages means. i.e. What do

- pyhd8ed1ab_0
- py_1003
- pyh9f0ad1d_2
- pyh44b312d_0
- 2

refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the build varient number. Because of CI/CD there are often changes that are so incremental they don't warrant a new version number. However, were you have an issue you could change the build without substantially changing anything major like dependencies.

[image]

As you might guess from the above, they're generated by conda and were [first implemented in conda 3.0](https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html)

Comment: Actually, it is very common to use builds to adjust dependencies. In fact, variants of a package compiled against different dependencies (e.g., specific BLAS implementations) are only distinguished by their build strings.